# Does AST have a patterns that outlines the types of data it should include?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree

I am thinking about how my AST should look like.
I found that standard AST is:

```
{ type: ..., value:..., children:...}
```

Unfortunately, I have a problem for packing, for example:

```
var x int = 100
```

I don't know how to pack it because this line for my will be parsed as:

```
ID: x
var_type: TINT
val_type: VINT
val: 100
```

Hence, my question is if there are any patterns for ASTs ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does AST have a patterns that outlines the types of data it should include?

Yes.  The pattern of an AST is the structure of the subject language.  Each AST contains enough information to reconstruct an utterance of that language wholly equivalent to (though not necessarily character-for-character identical with) the utterance from which the AST was constructed.

> I found that standard AST is:
>
> ```
> { type: ..., value:..., children:...}
> ```

That's a generic representation consistent with *any* tree. Not particularly helpful.

If you're trying to design the AST structure before writing a parser or some other formal description of the language then you are going about it backwards.  A typical approach would be to have a node type for each non-terminal in a formal grammar for the language.  The types of the children would correspond to the types of the symbols in the production.

For example, suppose the grammar rule for your example declaration were something like this:

```
var_decl_init: "var" identifier type "=" value EOL;
```

You might then have node types for `var_decl_init`, `identifier`, `type`, and `value`.  The first would have children of the latter three types, but no particular value of its own.  The latter three would probably not have children, but they would have values conveying the specific identifier ("x") data type ("int") and initial value (100):

```
var_init_decl()
  |
  +-- identifier("x")
  |
  +-- type("int")
  |
  +-- value(100)
```